# Why does calling 'pop' in this piece of assembly code cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I'm playing around with x86-64 assembly on Mac OS (using NASM 2.09 and 2.13, to catch bugs caused by NASM issues). I'm trying to implement function calls at the moment, and tried using the `push` and `pop` instructions, but the `pop` always seems to cause a segfault:

> `line 10: 41072 Segmentation fault: 11  ./result`

I've tried adjusting `rsp`, `rbp` etc manually, but the `pop` seems to be the issue. Any help would be appreciated!

```
section .data

default rel
global start
section .text

start:
    mov r12, 4
    push r12
    call label_0_print_digit
    (some stuff to exit program)

label_0_print_digit:
    pop r12
    (some stuff to print the digit - the issue persists even without this)
    ret
```

Comment: It's the `ret` after the `pop` that segfaults.  Use your debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code shown in the question, the `call` instruction puts the return address on the stack and the `pop` instruction removes the return address from the stack (putting it into `r12`).

The `ret` instruction then pops `4` from the stack and jumps there.  That isn't a valid code address, causing the fault.  `ret` is basically just `pop` into RIP.

---

To access parameters to a function that are on the stack, use `[rsp + 8]`, `[rsp + 16]`, etc., instead of `pop`.

The standard calling conventions for x86-64 pass integer args in registers instead of the stack, where the callee can use them directly.  And avoids the caller having to clean the stack after the function returns.  (There are 2: Linux/MacOS/etc. vs. Windows, using different registers.)

Comment: Note that the caller then needs to be aware that the parameters are still on the stack when the function returns.